# QWidget show function strange

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

two UI class, also called the theme.
And then write some control over events.
this  is  My main code

```
  if(ui==1){
    theme1=new theme1();
    connect(theme1->ui->btn_send1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Btn_Click_send1()));      
    connect(theme1->ui->btn_send2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Btn_Click_send2()));       

 }else{
     theme2=new theme2();
     connect(theme2->ui->btn_send1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Btn_Click_send1()));     
    connect(theme2->ui->btn_send2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Btn_Click_send2()));      
 }
 void testCode::Btn_Click_send1(){
  run1=new Run1();
   run1.show();
 }
void testCode::Btn_Click_send2(){
run2=new Run2();
run2.show();
```

}

UI is equal to 1, the code is good, but equal to other UI appears BUG。

Debugging, when errors are found in the show ()。

Run1 and Run2 Run in the other classes, but it is good.

I do not know why！！！ A week, and I am anxious！

thanks all!

Comment: Does Btn_Click_send1, Btn_Click_send2 get called when theme2 is instantiated? If Run1 and Run2 are independent classes and work fine, and you get the slots invoked for the second case, it should work. Try adding debug statements to your slots. Perhaps some code for theme2 and theme1 would help. Its difficult to guess with what you have posted.

Comment: The problem is that good times and bad, so I was very annoyed！

Comment: "but equal to other UI appears BUG" - And what is the bug?  Nothing you have posted gives us enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Similar to the ox75c9a4a0 " instructions reference " 0x00220c60 " memory of the memory can not be a written。But the wrong address is a

Comment: It is really difficult to understand your question, your objective and the problem.